# Multiple queries ordered by date created

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

We need several events to be listed and ordered by date. The events are stored in several tables, and selected by several queries. We can not use union + order by, because one table might have 3-4 columns while the other has around 20 columns.

We have come up with the following solution:

```
$stmt = $db->query("
  SELECT 'login' table, id, created
  FROM login
  WHERE date(created) BETWEEN 'somedate' AND 'somedate'
  UNION
  SELECT 'order' table, id, created
  FROM order
  WHERE date(created) BETWEEN 'somedate' AND 'somedate'
  UNION
  SELECT 'receipt' table, id, created
  FROM receipts
  WHERE date(created) BETWEEN 'somedate' AND 'somedate'
  ORDER BY created
");

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $sorted[] = array(
      "table" => $row['table'],
      "id" => $row['id']
    );
}

foreach (array_chunk($sorted, 5000) as $dataChunk) {
  foreach ($dataChunk as $row) {
    if ($row['table'] == "login") {
      $stmt = $db->query("
        SELECT some columns
        FROM logins
        WHERE id = ".$row['id']."
      ");
      $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
      if ($row_count != '0') {
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          do something
        }
      }
    }
    if ($row['table'] == "order") {
      $stmt = $db->query("
        SELECT some columns
        FROM logins
        WHERE id = ".$row['id']."
      ");
      $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
      if ($row_count != '0') {
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          do a lot here
        }
      }
    }
    if ($row['table'] == "receipt") {
      $stmt = $db->query("
        SELECT some columns
        FROM logins
        WHERE id = ".$row['id']."
      ");
      $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
      if ($row_count != '0') {
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          do something
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this solution there will be thousands of queries to our database, so our question is - can this be done in a better way?

Hope to hear from you guys... Thank you!

Comment: `order` is a reserved word, so something about the above doesn't quite ring true.

Comment: Oh, but it's just an example. We actually use "ordre", which is Norwegian for order. The code above works fine though, it's just that I reckon it's better ways to do this.

Comment: You can use the union, you just have to create dummy columns in the queries referencing table with fewer columns. Another possibility is to define a group of common columns and have them as the columns in each query, then for those with more than the basic columns, use concat to create a single column with name/value pairs for the columns unique to that table. You might even format as JSON to make exploding them easier.

Comment: Hmm.. It's kind of messy though, but perhaps a better solution because of the single query?

Answer (score 0):

** Add parentheses.  Else, the `ORDER BY` applies only to the `SELECT`:

```
( SELECT ... )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... )
ORDER BY ...
```

** Explicitly specify `UNION DISTINCT` if you expect dups and want to get rid of them (not likely based on your code), or `UNION ALL` for speed.

** For speed, and if you have `INDEX(created)`

```
WHERE created >= 'start...'
  AND created  < 'end...' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the parentheses have any effect, but thank you for the tip about UNION ALL. 

Can you please explain your last code. What's better about that than using BETWEEN.